# How to select a subset of the eval_dataset when training with Huggingface Trainer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

When using the Huggingface transformers' [`Trainer`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer), e.g.

```
# set training arguments - these params are not really tuned, feel free to change
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./",
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    per_device_train_batch_size=50,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=10,
    predict_with_generate=True,
    logging_steps=2,  # set to 1000 for full training
    save_steps=16,    # set to 500 for full training
    eval_steps=4,     # set to 8000 for full training
    warmup_steps=1,   # set to 2000 for full training
    max_steps=16,     # delete for full training
    # overwrite_output_dir=True,
    save_total_limit=1,
    #fp16=True, 
)

# instantiate trainer
trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=multibert,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_data.with_format("torch"),
    eval_dataset=eval_data.with_format("torch"),
)
```

#### Is there someway to randomly select/sample from the `eval_data` at every n `eval_steps` ?

E.g. I have tried

```
eval_data = eval_data.select(range(3000))

...

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=multibert,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_data.with_format("torch"),
    eval_dataset=eval_data.with_format("torch"),
)
```

But that would be statically defining the `eval_data` subset before the training.

#### Is it possible to do the selecting during the training and make it kind of select a different subset at every evaluation point?

Comment: Also asked on https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-sample-from-the-validation-set-when-using-trainer/25240?u=alvations

Comment: Questions:
1. will this ever be supported? 
2. Why does the eval set have to be fixed?
3. How do we avoid memory issues because when the train set samples data to log and the eval data set samples to log I've gotten OM issues. Can they run seperately?

Comment: HF Datasets use memory mapping to avoid loading the full dataset into memory. If you're running into OOM issues, it's likely caused by something other than the size of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use the [from_generator](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/v2.14.5/en/package_reference/main_classes#datasets.Dataset.from_generator) method with a custom generator that sub-selects data.

Answer (score 0):

use the `SubsetRandomSampler` from PyTorch to randomly select samples from the dataset at each evaluation step:

```
Import the `SubsetRandomSampler` from PyTorch:

from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler
```

Define evaluation dataset and the number of samples to select at each evaluation step:

```
eval_dataset = eval_data.with_format("torch")
num_samples_to_select = 3000
```

use `SubsetRandomSampler` to create a sampler that will randomly select `num_samples_to_select` samples at each evaluation step:

```
eval_dataset.sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(range(num_samples_to_select))
```

Set this modified `eval_dataset` as the eval_dataset in trainer:

```
trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=multibert,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_data.with_format("torch"),
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset.with_format("torch"),
)
```

at each evaluation step, the model will only evaluate on a randomly selected subset of the evaluation dataset, as specified by the `num_samples_to_select` variable. the selected subset will be different at each evaluation step, so model will be evaluated on different samples each time.